# Bootstrap with rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get bootstrap to work in my rails 6 web application but It won't work. I've followed multiple tutorials on youtube and on here but nothing seems to work. Any help where I might be going wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Gemfile: (First half that includes bootstrap)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.11', '>= 1.11.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
```

Application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require jquery
require bootstrap-sprockets
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

Application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

This is the result when i run it:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe in Rails 6, the accepted way to add Bootstrap is through Webpack. You can run `yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js` in your terminal. Then, add this to your `environment.js` file between the existing `const` and `module.exports` calls:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
```

Then, in your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` add this line:

```
require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
```

And, finally, in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` add this line:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: This is the most concise (and working!) answer I found after googling for hours. Thank you very much!